# API Facebook Post in album user

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use `graph v2.10`, `php sdk 5.5` I try to post on user album if is founded, but my script display an error:

> Graph return an error. Permission error.

When an user try to login to my website, user give permissions publish_actions, email, user_photos to app. But graph say permission error.

```
$albums = $fb->get('/me/albums', $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
        $album = array();
        foreach($albums as $k=>$v) {
            if($fetch_api['album_name'] == $v['name']) {
                $album[$fetch_api['album_name']] = $v['id'] ;
            }
        }

        if(count($album > 0)) {
            $data = [
              'message' => $_POST['msg'],
              'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('images/gallery-img1.jpg'),
            ];

            try {
              // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
              $response = $fb->post('/'.$album[$fetch_api['album_name']].'/photos', $data, $_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
              echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
              echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
              exit;
            }
```

Comment: did you check if the access token really includes the neccessary permissions? did you go through the review process?

Comment: No, i don t know how to do that, but basic info i can get. Check login code you will se There what i maked. I make just what i readed on github. I tryed to make like în docs from facebook, but is a variabile called session and script don t find him and i don t know what i need to add în session variabile to make it work. I can post on user timeline but not în album.

Comment: you can´t just post in any album afaik